# How to show 3d model in android java

Tags: java, android, 3d-model, rajawali

I want to show .gltf 3d models of all planets in android using java. I don't want to use camera, there will be image of space in the background and planet's 3d model will be on top of that. I also want it to move it like rotating it here. First I was searching for a library so that i can directly integrate it in my app but can't find.

I tried to implement it using Rajawali Renderer but i guess i am doing something wrong. Can anyone help me with this? If any library already available then please suggest otherwise please give me some code implementation of showing 3d model through a view or something.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/javagl/JglTF/tree/master/jgltf-browser?

Comment: @lance-java Thanks for recommending this but i haven't see this before, how can i use this in android exactly?

Comment: If you look at this [readme](https://github.com/javagl/JglTF/tree/master/jgltf-viewer) it gives a bit more insight. It seems there's two implementations... one based on [jogl](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) and the other based on [lwjgl](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/)

Comment: @lance-java but i am still unsure of how can i use this in android

Comment: ah... it seems android doesn't support `java.awt` so this won't work. Sorry for the noise